# Facebook API disappear when I use AJAX script

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

I have an error when I click on li link who contain javascript. 
The script JavaScript disappear and the text doesn't. 
Can you help me to resolve my problem, i don't find what is the problem.

Here is my AJAX script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu-game a").click(function()
{
    page=$(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: "./views/ContentAjax/"+page,
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){
            afficher(html);
        },
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
            afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
        }
    })
    return false;
});
});

function afficher(data)
{
$("#contenu").fadeOut(500,function()
{
    $("#contenu").empty();
    $("#contenu").append(data);
    $("#contenu").fadeIn(1000);
})
}
```

Here is the content I want to show when i click on the li link

```
<div id="game-content">


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


// The facebook API who disappear
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/assassinscreed.france" data-width="350" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
    </div>
    <div id="game-description">
        <p>The text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm sorry for my bad english, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need for dynamically loaded Social Plugins: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

And you really should not initialize the JavaScript SDK like that, initialize it on page load, not with AJAX. Else you can´t use `FB.XFBML.parse` anyway.